# Modern Sharepoint - Calendar/Events Item & Attendees

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, web-partmodern-w

I know modern pages/web parts have been out for a while but i'm just now getting to do some building in it.

I'm using the Modern events calendar how can I customize the webpart/form to show all the attendees or have people easily "RSVP" for an event?

I know that the event content type comes with "Attendees" but it does not show up in the "modern" for view.

All I want to do is show the "Attendees" label or add a "Going/Attending" button underneath the "Add to my calendar" (Red box in picture) that would then add the current user to the Attendees field.

Previously, I would customize the form in infopath, then have a workflow set the user into the attendees field, but that's not possible anymore.  Any documentation/guidance on the new process would be great.

Thank you guys,

-Mark

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no Attendees field in Events web part on Modern pages. It is by default.

As modern pages are continued improving, you can submit a feedback or vote the following user voice about this feature.
[Attendee List Of Events Web Part](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/36521653-attendee-list-of-events-web-part)